# What does 才 mean in 什么样的人才能做以下职业?

Tags: meaning

> 什 么 样 的人 才 能 做 以 下 职 业 ？

What is the meaning of 才 in this sentence. Or is the word 人才 or is the word 才能?  I think I understand the meaning of the sentence:

> What type of person can do this job?

But what is the meaning of 才？

Comment: Does this answer your question: [#1267](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/1267/12687)? Also, the sentence is problematic imo, indeed you can regard 人才 as a single word and still come up with a valid though rare interpretation, also, we usually use 从事 职业, not 做 职业.

Comment: I don't think that there is any other way to interpret this sentence.
If the author meant to say "ability(才能)", then he/she must at least add the proper symbols: 什 么 样 的人(才 能) 做 以 下 职 业 ？ 
so back to the question, I think "才~then" is an adverb to emphasize "能 able to"

Answer (score 3):

I would not agree that this 才 is 'only', I'd plump for 'then', or better still ignore it in translation. And this use of 'then' really means 'in that case'.

什么样的人才能做以下职业？
What kind of person then can do the following job/jobs?

怎样才能算出我的税金？
How (then) can I figure out my taxes?

努力工作才能取得成功。
(If you) Work hard, then you will be successful.

夜里才能赞美今天晴朗的天气。
(Wait till) evening, then you can praise today's fair weather.
Praise a fair day at night.

Answer (score 2):

The word in this case means 1. Only; 2 ... so that...

And "才"in this word doesn't mean talent.
You can use it as "才能" in a group. However, it doesn't mean talented ability in this sentence. it means "only can"

什么样的人：what kind of person

才能： （only）can

做以下职业：do the list of jobs below.

so in total, the sentence means:

**(only) what kind of person can do these jobs.**

it means a limitation of candidate that fits in this job.

if you use "才" as "so that", in this sentence it means: what special person it should be so that he/she can do this job.

Comment: What you say makes absolutely sense but I haven,t seen any grammar point like that in the wiki.
I look everything in the wiki chinese an other grammar books, and only referes to 才 as "only then" after somethings ocurrs (or only after)  
https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Expressing_%22only_after%22_with_%22cai%22

Or 才 as only after numbers.

Do you have any grammar reference of 才 as "only" to use it in questions like in the example. It does not matter if it is in chinese or english (online or offline). Thankyou very much.

Comment: @ANTXON Thank you very much for pointing that out. I think the "only when", "only then" "only after" is more accurate than "only" in this case. I should refer this link as well. In this example, it also means **(only after experienced a special experiences/education), the person could be qualified, and the question is, what kind of experiences/education it should be?**

Comment: @ANTXON and there is an example of "only" in this reference https://www.chineseboost.com/grammar/four-uses-cai2/. But in its reference it means **"not until"** and look for this sentence:  _"As well as talking about actual times, 才 can be used a little more idiomatically to talk about whether things qualify or meet certain standards."_

Answer (score 2):

> 什 么 样 的人 才 能 做 以 下 职 业 ？

As you suspected, it can be read either way:

> 1. 什 么 样 的人 [ 才 能] 做 以 下 职 业 ？
> 2. 什 么 样 的[人 才] 能 做 以 下 职 业 ？

We might need more context or how one reads the sentence to determine.  Their meanings are similar.